# save html file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am using javacsript  to read the content of the html file and i also alter the contents.. but i am not able to save that file..
i am reading and altering content of html file as:

```
   function edittheme(headtext, totext, bodytext, footertext) {
        alert(headtext);          
        var xmlDoc;
        if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            alert('IE');
            xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        }
        else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
        alert('moz');
            xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "doc", null);
        }
        alert('1');
     xmlDoc.async="false";
     xmlDoc.load("newthemes/theme3ex.html");       
     alert('0000');        
     document.getElementById('txtareahead').innerHTML = headtext;         
     document.getElementById('txtareato').innerHTML = totext;
     document.getElementById('txtareabody').innerHTML = bodytext;
     document.getElementById('txtareafooter').innerHTML = footertext;
     xmlDoc.save("newthemes/theme3ex.html");       
     location.href = "MailSender.aspx";
     }
```

how can the html file can be saved...
if it cannot be saved using javascript , is there any other way to save it according to my code?????..

Comment: by sending it back to your server, javascript can't save a file in the system, if you think about it it would be a security issue to have websites save files to the users computer

Comment: @lbu: i think if javascript can load the file , it can also save the file..

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing are completely different rights ;-) So only because of read-permissions there are no write-permissions. Otherwise, you could edit every file you can find in the web!

With plain JS it is not possible to write files, but with HTML5 and its [FileWriter-API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/). Have a look at the [first example](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/#examples). With this you can write files locally at the users hdd. If you want to save them on the server you have to send them back, just like lbu said.