# SAVING A WEBPAGE TO A DOC OR XLS FILE USING A SUBMIT BUTTON IN HTML

Tags: html, excel, ms-word

Good Day,

I not sure if this is possible but does any of you have an idea how to save a webpage as a doc or xls file using a submit button in html? I know that there is an option existing on a browser to save a webpage as word or excel by changing the extension file .html to .doc or .xls but i am trying to figure out if i can have that coded to a submit button.

Any help is highly appreciated; Thanks in Advance!

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT. And surely you can, in some sense, by using a server side script that converts the page or by linking to a pre-made .doc or .xls file. But no, there is no client-side magic that would do this.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795357/javascript-in-html-write-to-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223630/save-html-file-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

1. Export the page to PDF.
2. Open as PDF and save as XLS.

Not elegant, but works great. If you have a ton of data, very helpful.